# VBA detect when the user has performed an Undo or a Redo

Tags: vba, undo, redo

Is there a way in **VBA**, in the **Worksheet Change event**, to know that the user has done an **Undo or a Redo** and more specifically a Redo. Bearing in mind that <Ctrl + z> and <Ctrl + y> can be also used.

I have used a method comparing the opposite evolution of both Undo and Redo stack heights which works fine EXCEPT for 1 irreducible case:

**When the Redo stack height goes from 1 to 0 it can be for 2 reasons**:

- Either the user has performed the last Redo
- or the user has performed a simple change in the Worksheet that has emptied the Redo stack.

***I haven't found anything  to distinguish these 2 cases***.

`.OnAction` does not work for Builtin CommandBar Controls and no other property provides useful info.

The 2 CommandBar Controls used are:

1. Undo -> `Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(ID:=128)`
2. Redo -> `Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(ID:=129)`

The stack height count comes with the property `.ListCount` (protect with `On Error` if 0)

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: In Access I used to use `OnDirty` which tracks user entry. On entry, `OnDirty` goes to `true`, on `undo`, `OnDirty` goes false. I don't know if that exists in Excel.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately it does not work in Excel, the property is not known.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried `Application.OnUndo` but it's completely unusable. It requires a text, kills the stack and an `Application.Undo` in the procedure generates an error. And anyway `Application.OnRepeat` does not seem to be the counterpart of `Application.OnUndo`. It only reacts to a <Ctrl + y>, does not display the text (!) and blocks the Redo button and a VBA Redo (`Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(ID:=129).Execute`)